# sum html table column after filtering javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I use this function `CalColumnHistDEPOSITO()` to sum a table column as it loads from server side to my html page. But when I apply a filter it continuous to sum the entire table ignoring the filter.

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';

var TableFilter = (function() {
 var Arr = Array.prototype;
  var input;
  
  function onInputEvent(e) {
   input = e.target;
   var table1 = document.getElementsByClassName(input.getAttribute('data-table'));
   Arr.forEach.call(table1, function(table) {
    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
     Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, filter);
                CalColumnHistDEPOSITO();
    });
   });
  }

  function filter(row) {
   var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
       //console.log(text);
      var val = input.value.toLowerCase();
      //console.log(val);
   row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

  }

  return {
   init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('table-filter');
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
     input.oninput = onInputEvent;
          
    });
   }
  };
 
 })();

  /*console.log(document.readyState);
 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      console.log(document.readyState);
   TableFilter.init();
  }
 }); */
  
 TableFilter.init(); 
})();




 function CalColumnHistDEPOSITO() {
            var table = document.getElementById("VendasHistoryTable"); 
            // var table = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 tr td:first-child");
            var sumVal = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
            document.getElementById("Tprice").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2);
  
     }
```

```css
/*DARK BACKGROWND ROWS 3D EFFECT*/
  .dark3Dtable{/*CENTER TABLE*/
  margin-left:auto; 
     margin-right:auto;
     
 }
    
  

       .dark3Dtable tr:nth-child(even) {
       background: linear-gradient(180deg, #364e63, #121a21 70%);
       
       }
      .dark3Dtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, #364e63, #121a21 70%)
      }

      .dark3Dtable tbody{
   
  overflow:auto;
  height:300px;

}


 /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
 .dark3Dtable tr{
         color: white;
   transition:all .25s ease-in-out
 }
 
 /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .dark3Dtable tr:hover {
    
           cursor: pointer;
            color: #000;
           /* text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFF, 0 0 10px #FFF, 0 0 15px #FFF, 0 0 20px #49ff18, 0 0 30px #49FF18, 0 0 40px #49FF18, 0 0 55px #49FF18, 0 0 75px #49ff18;*/
            
           background-color: #111;
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,  #000, #fff  40%, #000);
            }
            
     
    .dark3Dtable th{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #364e63, #121a21 70%, #364e63);
            background-color: white;
            color: white;
            }
    .dark3Dtable th:hover{
            color: white;
            }
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h2>Vanilla JS Table filter</h2>
  <input type="text" class="table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Item to filter.." />


 <strong> sum of column 4 PRICE: $ <span id="Tprice"></span></strong>
<br>
  <table id="VendasHistoryTable" class="order-table table dark3Dtable">
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Price</th>
           <th>date</th>
      </tr>
        </thead>

      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
        <td>99.80</td>
        <td>15/02/2020</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Jane Vanda</td>
        <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
        <td>9876543210</td>
        <td>349.51</td>
        <td>19/02/2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
        <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
        <td>6754328901</td>
        <td>199.50</td>
        <td>18/05/2020</td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
        <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
        <td>6754328901</td>
        <td>199.00</td>
        <td>25/05/2020</td>
      </tr>

  </table>

</section>
```

What do I modify on the function CalColumnHistDEPOSITO() in order for it to reflect my filter? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the lines within the for loop in `CalColumnHistDEPOSITO()` method as below. Because the filter you have is just to hide them. They are still part of the DOM. During the calculation you need to exclude them based on the style display attribute whether its `table-row` or not

```
for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
  var row = table.rows[i];
  if(row.style.display == 'table-row')
    sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(row.cells[3].innerHTML);
}
```

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';

var TableFilter = (function() {
 var Arr = Array.prototype;
  var input;
  
  function onInputEvent(e) {
   input = e.target;
   var table1 = document.getElementsByClassName(input.getAttribute('data-table'));
   Arr.forEach.call(table1, function(table) {
    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
     Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, filter);
                CalColumnHistDEPOSITO();
    });
   });
  }

  function filter(row) {
   var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
       //console.log(text);
      var val = input.value.toLowerCase();
      //console.log(val);
   row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

  }

  return {
   init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('table-filter');
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
     input.oninput = onInputEvent;
          
    });
   }
  };
 
 })();

  /*console.log(document.readyState);
 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      console.log(document.readyState);
   TableFilter.init();
  }
 }); */
  
 TableFilter.init(); 
})();




 function CalColumnHistDEPOSITO() {
            var table = document.getElementById("VendasHistoryTable"); 
            // var table = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 tr td:first-child");
            var sumVal = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
            var row = table.rows[i];
            if(row.style.display == 'table-row')
            sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(row.cells[3].innerHTML);
            }
            document.getElementById("Tprice").innerHTML = sumVal.toFixed(2);
  
     }
```

```css
/*DARK BACKGROWND ROWS 3D EFFECT*/
  .dark3Dtable{/*CENTER TABLE*/
  margin-left:auto; 
     margin-right:auto;
     
 }
    
  

       .dark3Dtable tr:nth-child(even) {
       background: linear-gradient(180deg, #364e63, #121a21 70%);
       
       }
      .dark3Dtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, #364e63, #121a21 70%)
      }

      .dark3Dtable tbody{
   
  overflow:auto;
  height:300px;

}


 /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
 .dark3Dtable tr{
         color: white;
   transition:all .25s ease-in-out
 }
 
 /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .dark3Dtable tr:hover {
    
           cursor: pointer;
            color: #000;
           /* text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFF, 0 0 10px #FFF, 0 0 15px #FFF, 0 0 20px #49ff18, 0 0 30px #49FF18, 0 0 40px #49FF18, 0 0 55px #49FF18, 0 0 75px #49ff18;*/
            
           background-color: #111;
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,  #000, #fff  40%, #000);
            }
            
     
    .dark3Dtable th{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #364e63, #121a21 70%, #364e63);
            background-color: white;
            color: white;
            }
    .dark3Dtable th:hover{
            color: white;
            }
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h2>Vanilla JS Table filter</h2>
  <input type="text" class="table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Item to filter.." />


 <strong> sum of column 4 PRICE: $ <span id="Tprice"></span></strong>
<br>
  <table id="VendasHistoryTable" class="order-table table dark3Dtable">
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Price</th>
           <th>date</th>
      </tr>
        </thead>

      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
        <td>99.80</td>
        <td>15/02/2020</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Jane Vanda</td>
        <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
        <td>9876543210</td>
        <td>349.51</td>
        <td>19/02/2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
        <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
        <td>6754328901</td>
        <td>199.50</td>
        <td>18/05/2020</td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
        <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
        <td>6754328901</td>
        <td>199.00</td>
        <td>25/05/2020</td>
      </tr>

  </table>

</section>
```

Comment: I see, It needs to look through the rows so it reflects the changes. Thank you.

Comment: If it resolves your issue you can accept and upvote the answer

Comment: what do you suggest if I'm using another type of filter? I tried changing the  if(row.style.display == 'table-row') to something else.

Comment: Yes whatever is the attribute you use for filtering the hide/show need to be used here to exclude or include that row in the sum.